# How to insert text between the page numbers?

Tags: wp-link-pages, nextpage

Inside my article I use the tag `<!--nextpage-->`. Now how to insert text between the page numbers. In HTML it should look like this:

```
<div class="postlink">
<p style="text-align: center;">my test 1</p>

<a rel="nofollow" href="https://domen.com/linkpost/2/"> 2 </a>
<a rel="nofollow" href="https://domen.com/linkpost/3/"> 3 </a>
<a rel="nofollow" href="https://domen.com/linkpost/4/"> 4 </a>
<a rel="nofollow" href="https://domen.com/linkpost/5/"> 5</a>

<p style="text-align: center;">my text 2</p>

<a rel="nofollow" href="https://domen.com/linkpost/6/"> 6 </a>
<a rel="nofollow" href="https://domen.com/linkpost/7/"> 7 </a>
<a rel="nofollow" href="https://domen.com/linkpost/8/"> 8 </a>

<p style="text-align: center;">my text 3</p>

<a rel="nofollow" href="https://domen.com/linkpost/9/"> 9 /a>
<a rel="nofollow" href="https://domen.com/linkpost/10/"> 10</a>
<a rel="nofollow" href="https://domen.com/linkpost/11/"> 11 </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [`wp_link_pages()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_link_pages/) with `'next_or_number'` set to `'number'` (or not set at all, it's the default), which you presumably are, then you can use the [`wp_link_pages_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_link_pages_link/) filter.

`wp_link_pages_link` lets you filter the HTML for each individual page link that's output. The 2nd argument, `$i`, gives you the page number. You can use this to conditionally output HTML before or after the link depending on the current page number.

For example, if I wanted to output a `<br>` tag after the second link, I would do this:

```
function wpse_296614_page_link( $link, $i ) {
    if ( $i === 2 ) {
        $link = $link . '<br>';
    }

    return $link;
}
add_filter( 'wp_link_pages_link', 'wpse_296614_page_link', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: So I use wp_link_pages() , but the text I need to insert between pages a few times, so it's not suitable, because there you can only print it once, after a certain page

Comment: Well it's the only way to do it, so it is suitable. Just change the condition. You could use `$i %2 === 0` to check if the current page is even numbered, for example. Or you could add multiple conditions and it will output if  any of them are true. There's plenty of ways to use this to do what you want.

Comment: Thank you. They helped to find a solution, but not completely, just can not figure out how to specify after which page number to output the text. Can you know what you need to add to this code?
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/296987/138114

Comment: I’ve explained it. Check the value of `$i`.